# Enable Javascript in tkinterweb python

Tags: javascript, python, tkinter

I am using python 3.9 and tried to view website in tkinter window with the help of tkinterweb but for some websites it asks for enabling javascript so please tell how to do that... Also it is not loading youtube videos.

Below is my code:

```
import tkinterweb
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
frame = tkinterweb.HtmlFrame(root)
frame.load_website('https://www.google.com/')
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't think tkinterweb supports web pages that use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have been testing tkinterweb using some websites, and it looks like the library does not support JS, unfortunately.